# Why I can't find ip_vs module or use ipvsadm when I add privileged

Tags: docker

I run the docker container by ubuntu:14.04 images

`$ uname -a

Linux a1786ab89b52 3.13.0-55-generic #92-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 14 18:32:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

and I use this command to run my container

`docker run --privileged  -ti images_id`

and I run this command

`modinfo ip_vs`

and I will get this error

`libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-55-generic/modules.dep.bin'
modinfo: ERROR: Module alias ip_vs not found.`

if I install ipvsadm and run it will get error like this,because system can't use ip_vs kernel module。

why I can't use it,I add privileged option

Answer (score 0):

e.....maybe I find answer by myself

if we want to use ipvsadm tool to modify rules in Docekr container,we must be sure the IPVS kernel module on your Docker Host machine,or ipvsadm in your Docker Host machine

if you use Ubuntu,please use this command in your Docker Host 

`sudo apt-get install ipvsadm`

and when you run container must add --privileged.like this

`docker run --privileged -ti ubuntu`